# Why does Sonata ask for AdminInterface

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, sonata-admin, sonata

I am trying to use Sonata Admin and followed the documentation step-by-step: https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/getting_started/creating_an_admin.html

However, as I try to run the project it gives the following error:

> In AdminSearchCompilerPass.php line 75:   Service
> "admin.media" must implement
> `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AdminInterface`.

This is my MediaAdmin Class:

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

final class MediaAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form): void
    {
        $form->add('name', TextType::class);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagrid): void
    {
        $datagrid->add('name');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $list): void
    {
        $list->addIdentifier('name');
    }

    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $show): void
    {
        $show->add('name');
    }
}
```

This is my services.yaml

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    admin.media:
        class: App\Admin\MediaAdmin
        tags: 
            - { name: sonata.admin, model_class: App\Entity\Media, manager_type: orm, label: Media }
```

Comment: Can you check you config for Sonata matches what's shown in the guide? https://symfony.com/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/current/getting_started/installation.html#configure-the-installed-bundles

Also long shot but delete your vendor folder and do `composer install` just to be sure.

Comment: I did everything as instructed in the guide. I also tried deleting the "vendor" folder and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was just confronted with the same error. It was due to a class name miss-typing in `services.yaml`.

When encountering this error, one should check that the configured Admin class exists and can be loaded by the auto-loader:

- Filename and class name are the same (e.g. `App\Admin\MediaAdmin` class is in `src/Admin/MediaAdmin.php`.
- Class name in `services.yaml` matches the Admin class.

The error is miss-leading. I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/7969).